# Does using thorn whip to pull an enemy who is grappling an ally break their grapple on that ally?

Tags: dnd-5e, grapple, cantrips

Assuming two medium humanoid types with 5ft reach are the grappler/grappled and the thorn whip pulls the grappler 10ft against their will towards the caster. Does this satisfy the conditions to end a grapple per the final point of the grappled condition, quoted below:

> The condition also ends if an effect removes the grappled creature from the reach of the grappler or grappling effect, such as when a creature is hurled away by the *thunderwave* spell.

Comment: Hi and welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] when you get a chance. This is a good first question, and there are similar such questions already. I have marked this as a duplicate of one such question, but if this other question doesn't quite provide the answer you were looking for, you can [edit](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/posts/145590/edit) your question to bring it to our community's attention to be reopened again. Hope you find your answer and happy gaming!